# Ruby on Rails javascript assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, assets

I have a problems with javascripts assets in Ruby on Rails.
Descripttion:
I have two files in app/assets/javascript folder.

> 1. "constans.js" include a constant array  "var FEATURES = new Array["A","B","C"]"
> 2. "route.js.erb" <%= FEATURES[1]  %>

Now , I'm implementing my function in "route.js.erb" but I can't access the "FEATURES" array ? 
I searched on Google but can't not find the solution.
So, anybody can help me? Thanks!
( my first question in stack overflow , sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Where your included your "constans.js" file.. via application.js or in the layout.. can you post that code?

Comment: Can you access `FEATURES` from browser console?

Comment: I've got the answer. Javascript constant can not be accessed in Rails tag . Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 1):

use

window.FEATURES =  new Array["A","B","C"]"

in constants.js

and make sure that the constants.js is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are several important factors:

> 1. [Scoping of the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)
> 2. Calling the variable in ERB

**Scope**

First, you need to ensure your variable is scoped globally. To do this, you've declared the variable in `constants.js`, so you need to ensure this is called before the `routes.js.erb` file. You should also take `@user3243476`'s advice & append it to the `window` object:

```
#js/constants.js
window.FEATURES = new Array["A","B","C"]
```

---

**ERB**

Secondly, you're calling `routes.js.erb` (which is fine), but inside you're calling `<%= FEATURES["1"] %>`. Problem. This is calling a Rails  constant, *not* the JS one. This means even if your variable's scope is global, you're trying to call one which doesn't exist.

You'll need to do this:

```
#js/routes.js.erb
alert(FEATURES["1"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I can't not call Js constant in Rails tag . So I got another way to solve my problem already.